# i need to set one IP in profile 202.32.123.130

Tags: profile, login

i need to set one IP in profile 202.32.123.130.But there are 2 IP Start Address IP End Address fields are mandatory.how can I add one IP  (202.32.123.130)

Answer (score 2):

Give both Start and End IP address with the same value. Which will consider it as single IP.

Comment: Yes. This could work.